# cannot implicitly convert type 'syste.collections.generics.list' to 'system.collections.generics.list'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm getting error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Collections.Generics.List<MeritMaste_QuestionPeparsettings>` to `System.Collections.Generics.List<MeritMaste.data.MeritMAster_QuestionPeparSettng>`

1. is it a database connection problem ?
2. is it a database connection error?

---

```
public class DataManager
{
    public static void OnlineExamLists(
        out List<MeritMaste_QuestionPaperSettings> examQuestionSettings,
        out List<MeritMaster_QuestionBank> questionBanks, string examCode)
    {

        using (var dbcontext = new meritmasterEntities())
        {

            // var exam_code = dbcontext.MeritMaste_QuestionPaperSettings.Where(m => m.ID == examCode).FirstOrDefault().ex_code;
            //(from k in dbcontext.MeritMaste_QuestionPaperSettings where k.Status == true && k.ID == examCode select k.ex_code).ToList();

            examQuestionSettings = (from k in dbcontext.MeritMaste_QuestionPaperSettings 
                                    where k.Status == true && k.ex_code == examCode 
                                    select k).ToList();

            var examsettingslocal = examQuestionSettings.FirstOrDefault();

            var kabqu = new List<MeritMaster_QuestionBank>();
            var queBank = examsettingslocal == null
                ? kabqu
                : (from k in dbcontext.MeritMaster_QuestionBank
                    where k.Status == true && k.Course_ID == examsettingslocal.CourseId
                    select k).ToList();
            // questionBanks = queBank.ToList();

            var questionbanklocal = dbcontext.MeritMaste_QuestionPaperSettings.ToList();


            questionBanks = (from es in examQuestionSettings.ToList()
                                join qb in queBank.ToList() on new {p1 = (int) es.CourseId, p2 = (int) es.QuestionIds} equals
                                    new {p1 = (int) qb.Course_ID, p2 = (int) qb.ID}

                                where es.ex_code == examCode && es.Status == true && qb.Status == true
                                select qb).ToList();
            //join a in questionpaperlocal.ToList() on k.QuestionIds equals a.ID
            //where k.Status == true && a.Status == true
            ////orderby a.Id ascending
            //select k
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the classes `MeritMaste_QuestionPaperSettings` and `MeritMaste.data.MeritMAster_QuestionPeparSettng` or show how they related to each other.

Answer (score 0):

`MeritMaste_QuestionPeparsettings` and `MeritMaste.data.MeritMAster_QuestionPeparSettng` are two different types to the compiler, and there doesn't exist a convertion between these two types.

You need to either define a conversion (implicit or explicit), or manually convert them. You can do so using various techniques, such as using `IQueryable.ForAll`, or `IEnumerable.Select` extension methods.

Comment: sorry @Yuval . i could not get u . can u give little more description or code to solve my error. kindly help me how to convert